# 10 fold size increase when reading file into struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to read a csv file into a struct containing a vector of vector of strings. The file contains ~2 million lines and size on disk is ~350 mb. When I read the file into struct `top` shows me that the on reading the full file, the program is now using almost 3.5GB of my memory. I have used vector reserve to try to limit vector capacity increase on push_back.

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<array>
#include<ctime>
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;

struct datStr{
  vector<string> colNames;
  vector<vector<string>> data;
};

datStr readBoost(string fileName)
{
  datStr ds;
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(fileName);
  string line;
  getline(inFile, line);
  vector<string> colNames;
  stringstream ss(line);
  string item;
  int i = 0;
  vector<int> colTypeInt;
  while(getline(ss, item, ','))
  {
      item.erase( remove( item.begin(), item.end(), ' ' ), item.end() );
      colNames.push_back(item);
      vector<string> colVec;
      ds.data.push_back(colVec);
      ds.data[i].reserve(3000000);
      i++;
  }

  int itr = 0;
  while(getline(inFile, line))
  {
      vector<string> rowStr;
      boost::split(rowStr, line, boost::is_any_of(","));
      for(int ktr = 0; ktr < rowStr.size(); ktr++)
      {
          rowStr[ktr].erase( remove( rowStr[ktr].begin(), rowStr[ktr].end(), ' ' ), rowStr[ktr].end() );
          ds.data[ktr].push_back(rowStr[ktr]);
      }
      itr++;
  }
 int main()
 {
  datStr ds = readBoost("file.csv");
  while(true)
  {
  }
 }
```

PS: The last `while` is just so I can monitor the memory usage on completion of the program.
Is this something expected when using vectors or am I missing something here?
Another interesting fact. I started adding up size and capacity for each string in the read loop. Surprisingly it just adds up to 1/10 of what I am shown in top on ubuntu? Could it be that top is misreporting or my compiler is allocating too much space?

Comment: How exactly are you measuring the memory use? `delete` and `free` are not required to immediately release memory back to the OS - the runtime can hold on to the memory to satisfy future allocation requests. Your program may be using only a portion of what it has allocated to it.

Comment: Are you implying it could be an OS issue?

Comment: The lifetime of the vector `rowStr` is only inside the scope of the enclosing `while` loop. You are copying raw pointers to the stings in `rowStr` and all of those pointers are invalidated when `rowStr` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. Changing to a vector of `char*` is going to be a resource management headache and probably not what you want to do.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, have realized as much in the last couple of hours. Not as simple as changing string to char*. But if not that, then I am left with data which can't be handled by my machine. Still no answers as to optimize string capacity (original question).

Comment: Are these strings ever modified during the lifetime of your program or are they just read once and then only referenced and not changed while the program runs?

Comment: No modifications once read. Only referenced to process the data.

Comment: How about just reading the whole file into a single allocated block of memory. You can then step through the block, saving a non-owning raw pointer to the start of each string and storing a trailing null in the space or delimiter after each string to terminate it. Only the big block owns the allocated memory and it can be released with a single `delete[]` when you're done. The vectors only hold non-owning pointers and therefore don't leak anything when they are destroyed.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, will it be possible to give a quick example?

Comment: It will take me a little time to write a small, complete example.

Comment: Okay, here is an example at [this link to ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ScHLMC). It's simplified but it does read a csv file into a `vector<vector<char*>>`, keeping the data separate from the container, and prints the strings out. It works in my brief testing but may hide terrible bugs so use at your own risk. I mainly wanted to show one way to store the data separate from a container of non-owning pointers.

Comment: That works fine. so far found no other bugs

Comment: Another interesting fact. I started adding up size and capacity for each string in the read loop. Surprisingly it just adds up to 1/10 of what I am shown in top on ubuntu? Could it be that top is misreporting or my compiler is allocating too much space?

Comment: Regardless of what the issue with your code might be, if you're reading a complete 350 MB text file into memory, you're probably already doing something wrong. You might want to consider [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) (Linux), [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761) (Windows) or similar...

Comment: @DevSolar, I also saw a couple of other comments mentioning the same. I have a 6G RAM system. Why do you think its such a big deal to read just a 350 mb file? Its less than 10% of available memory. I am looking at mmap.

Comment: @NaveenSharma: Because as a programmer, I am striving for efficiency and improvement. I also very seldom write programs in C++ that are one-shot, personal-use only, or run in isolation. (Other apps might want a piece of that RAM as well.) If you cannot be bothered with proper design, why worry about the RAM usage anyway? Or programming, for that matter?

Comment: My question to you was on is there a general rule of thumb or design principle? But I guess sarcasm and judgement should do fine.

Comment: @NaveenSharma: Sorry, I thought it was obvious. Unless you really *need* the whole file in memory at once (like, a graphics file), you really want to either process it block-wise, or (if that doesn't cut it, like in a database use-case) map the file into memory (`mmap()`). Reading the whole file makes your app wait first on the I/O, then on the CPU, which makes for a very poor overall profile (both in performance and in resource usage). I don't see what your code is indended to achieve, but I really doubt you need those 350 MB in memory all at once. It's a code smell.

Comment: you said you have 350 Mb of file with 2 millions of line, this leads to on average 175 bytes per line. Now, if you have a lot of short string (few chars), you can end up using a lot more memory due to the short string optimization that std::string is implementing. Basically, if the string is short enough the compiler will use a fixed length stack memory instead of heap allocated one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested your code with an input file that has `1886850` lines of text, with a size of `105M`.

With your code, the memory consumption was about 2.5G.

Then, I started modifying how data is stored.

**First test:**

Change `datStr` to:

```
struct datStr{
    vector<string> colNames;
    vector<string> lines;
};
```

This reduced the memory consumption to `206M`. That's more than 10 fold reduction in size. It's clear that the penalty for using

```
vector<vector<string>> data;
```

is rather stiff.

**Second test:**

Change `datStr` to:

```
struct datStr{
    vector<string> colNames;
    vector<string> lines;
    vector<vector<string::size_type>> indices;
};
```

with `indices` keeping track of where the tokens in `lines` start. You can extract the tokens from each line by using `lines` and `indices`.

With this change, the memory consumption went to `543MB` but sill is five times smaller than the original.

**Third test**

Change `dataStr` to:

```
struct datStr{
    vector<string> colNames;
    vector<string> lines;
    vector<vector<unsigned int>> indices;
};
```

With this change, the memory consumption came down to `455MB`. This should work if you don't expect your lines to be longer or equal to `UINT_MAX`.

**Fourth Test**

Change `dataStr` to:

```
struct datStr{
    vector<string> colNames;
    vector<string> lines;
    vector<vector<unsigned short>> indices;
};
```

With this change, the memory consumption came down to `278MB`. This should work if you don't expect your lines to be longer or equal to `USHRT_MAX`. For this case, the overhead of `indices` is really small, only `72MB`.

Here's the modified code I used for my tests.

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<array>
#include<ctime>
// #include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;

struct datStr{
    vector<string> colNames;
    vector<string> lines;
    vector<vector<unsigned short>> data;
};

void split(vector<unsigned short>& rowStr, string const& line)
{
   string::size_type begin = 0;
   string::size_type end = line.size();
   string::size_type iter = begin;
   while ( iter != end)
   {
      ++iter;
      if ( line[iter] == ',' )
      {
         rowStr.push_back(static_cast<unsigned short>(begin));
         ++iter;
         begin = iter;
      }
   }
   if (begin != end )
   {
      rowStr.push_back(static_cast<unsigned short>(begin));
   }
}

datStr readBoost(string fileName)
{
   datStr ds;
   ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open(fileName);
   string line;
   getline(inFile, line);
   vector<string> colNames;
   stringstream ss(line);
   string item;
   int i = 0;
   vector<int> colTypeInt;
   while(getline(ss, item, ','))
   {
      item.erase( remove( item.begin(), item.end(), ' ' ), item.end() );
      ds.colNames.push_back(item);
   }

   int itr = 0;
   while(getline(inFile, line))
   {
      ds.lines.push_back(line);
      vector<unsigned short> rowStr;
      split(rowStr, line);
      ds.data.push_back(rowStr);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   datStr ds = readBoost(argv[1]);
   while(true)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Some very interesting tests indeed! Let me try them out and revert.

Comment: Runs fine with the while loop.  On removing it, gives me segmentation fault. Memory consumption definitely as you have reported.

Answer (score 2):

Your `vector<vector<string>>` suffers from the costs of indirection (pointer members to dynamically allocated memory), housekeeping (members supporting `size()`/`end()`/`capacity()`), and the housekeeping and rounding-up internal to the dynamic memory allocation functions... if you look at the first graph titled *Real memory consumption for different string lengths* [here](http://jovislab.com/blog/?p=76) it suggests total overheads around 40-45 bytes *per string* for a 32 bit app built with G++ 4.6.2, though an implementation could potentially get this as low as 4 bytes for strings of up to ~4 characters.  Then there's waste for `vector` overheads....

You can address the issue in any of several ways, depending on your input data and efficiency needs:

- store `vector<std::pair<string, Column_Index>>`, where `Column_Index` is a class you write that records the offsets in the string where each field appear
- store `vector<std::string>` where column values are padded to known maximum widths, which will help most if the lengths are small, fixed and/or similar (e.g. date/times, small monetary amounts, ages)
- memory map the file, then store offsets (but unquoting/unescaping is an issue - you could do that in-place, e.g. `abc""def` or `abc\"def` (whichever you support) -> `abc"deff`)
- with the last two approaches, you can potentially overwrite the character after each field with a NUL if that's useful to you, so you can treat the fields as "C"-style ASCIIZ NUL-terminated strings
- if some/all fields contain values like values like say 1.23456789012345678... where the textual representation may be longer than a binary inbuilt type (`float`, `double`, `int64_t`), doing a conversion before storage makes sense
- similarly, if there's a set of repeating values - like a field of what are logically enumeration identifiers, you can encoding them as integers, or if the values are repetitive but not known until runtime, you can create a bi-directional mapping from incrementing indices to values

Answer (score 1):

A couple things come to mind:

You say your file has about 2 million lines, but you reserve space for 3 million `strings` *for each column*. Even if you only have one column, that's a lot of wasted space. If you have a bunch of columns, that's a *ton* of wasted space. It might be informative to see how much    space difference it makes if you don't `reserve` at all.

`string` has a small<sup>*</sup> but nonzero amount of overhead that you're paying for every single field in your 2-million line file. If you really need to hold all the data in memory at once and it's causing problems to do so, this may actually be a case where you're better off just using `char*` instead of `string`. But I'd only resort to this if adjusting `reserve` doesn't help.

<sup>*</sup> The overhead due to metadata is small, but if the `string`s are allocating extra capacity for their internal buffers, that could really add up. See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935177/can-stdstring-capacity-be-changed-for-optimisation).

---

Update: The problem with your update is that you are storing pointers to temporary `std::string` objects in `datStr`. By the time you get around to printing, those `string`s have been destroyed and your pointers are wild.

If you want a simple, safe way to store your strings in `datStr` that doesn't allocate more space than it needs, you could use something like this:

```
class TrivialReadOnlyString
{
private:
    char* m_buffer;

public:
    TrivialReadOnlyString(const std::string& src)
    {
       InitFrom(src.c_str());
    }

    TrivialReadOnlyString(const TrivialReadOnlyString& src)
    {
       InitFrom(src.m_buffer);
    }

    ~TrivialReadOnlyString()
    {
       delete[] m_buffer;
    }

    const char* Get()
    {
       return m_buffer;
    }

private:
    void InitFrom(const char* src)
    {
       // Can switch to the safe(r) versions of these functions
       // if you're using vc++ and it complains.
       size_t length = strlen(src);
       m_buffer = new char[length + 1];
       strcpy(m_buffer, src);
    }
};
```

There are a lot of further enhancements that could be made to this class, but I think it is sufficient for your program's needs as shown. This will fragment memory more than Blastfurnace's idea of storing the whole file in a single buffer. however.

If there is a lot of repetition in your data, you might also consider "folding" the repeats into a single object to avoid redundantly storing the same strings in memory over and over (flyweight pattern).

Comment: I removed the reserve and it still didn't make any difference. The memory used was still the same. I was using 3million as a safeguard for bigger files. Let me try char*

Comment: It's also possible that `vector`'s exponential dynamic resizing is overshooting by a big margin when you don't reserve at all. You could try reserving the exact number of lines (plus a *small* amount of padding) to get a best-case estimate.

Comment: yea, played around with reserve. no luck. going to try list first and then string to char*

Comment: It might also be interesting to exit the while on kbhit or something, let ds go out of scope, and then see how much of the 3.5GB is freed up.

Comment: tried deque, list, none helped. should be string only. going to try char*.

Comment: i tried the shrink_to_fit but it gives the exact same amount of memory usage

Comment: Note that `shrink_to_fit` doesn't necessarily do anything (it's up to the implementer). You'd have to either trace in or do a before/after comparison of size vs. capacity to be sure.

Comment: I got that but how do I ensure it works? What I just did shows that it didn't.

Comment: You can also try the `swap` trick, but that isn't guaranteed to work either. If it doesn't, there's no way to avoid the extra capacity except by not using `string`.

Comment: Have you tried without using reserve at all? My understanding is that reserve is mostly for speed optimisation. If it's significantly smaller without using reserve you can then consider if it is still fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Indulge me while I take a *very different* approach in answering your question. Others have already answered your direct question quite well, so let me provide another perspective entirely.

Do you realize that you could store that data in memory with a single allocation, plus one pointer for each line, or perhaps one pointer per cell?

On a 32 bit machine, that's 350MB + 8MB (or 8MB * number columns).

Did you know that it's easy to parallelize CSV parsing?

The problem you have is layers and layers of bloat. `ifstream`, `stringstream`, `vector<vector<string>>`, and `boost::split` are wonderful if you don't care about size or speed. All of that can be done more directly and at lower cost.

In situations like this, where size and speed do matter, you should consider doing things the manual way. Read the file using an API from your OS. Read it into a single memory location, and modify the memory in place by replacing commas or EOLs with '\0'. Store pointers to those C strings in your datStr and you're done.

You can write similar solutions for variants of the problem. If the file is too large for memory, you can process it in pieces. If you need to convert data to other formats like floating point, that's easy to do. If you'd like to parallelize parsing, that's far easier without the extra layers between you and your data.

Every programmer should be able to choose to use convenience layers or to use simpler methods. If you lack that choice, you won't be able to solve some problems.